# includePath в Visual Studio Code не видны хедеры

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

IntelliSense в VS Code не видит хедеры, установленные в `/usr/local/include`. Я собрал и установил GLUT для OpenGL, но по умолчанию хедеры и либы установились не в `/usr`, а в `/usr/local`. Я узнал, что можно настроить includePath в `c_cpp_properties.json`, которые VS Code создает в директории с проектом. Этот файл у меня выглядит так:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Но почему-то IntelliSense все равно не видит хедеры. Что делать?

Comment: А как это проявляется? Он ругаться на что то? И установлен ли ReSarper.. может он подменяет действия `IntelliSense`

Comment: @NewView, всплывает окошко с предложением сконфигурировать IntelliSense, чтобы найти пропущенные хедеры. Подсвечен зеленым и красным #include <gl/glut.h>:please update your includePath.

Comment: В свойствах проекта попробуйте указать дополнительные пути к инклюде с полным путём, думаю поможет.